# Custom buttons design for stepper

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-layout

I am implementing Stepper in my flutter app. I am stuck on a position where I need to design continue and cancel/back button custom design. How I am trying to identify how I can implement my custom design to this.

Comment: post your `controlsBuilder` property

Comment: I found the solution now as you mentioned with controlBuilder.

Answer (score 6):

I found solution to design custom buttons for Stepper. It can be achieved by controlsBuilder. Here is my sample code:

```
controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                            return Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(height: AppSize.smallMedium,),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    ProgressButtonWidget(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                                      buttonTitle: Constants.continueButton,
                                      tapCallback: (){
                                        setState(() {
                                          // update the variable handling the current step value
                                          // going back one step i.e adding 1, until its the length of the step
                                          if (currentStep < mySteps.length - 1) {
                                            currentStep = currentStep + 1;
                                          } else {
                                            currentStep = 0;
                                          }
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: AppSize.small,),
                                    ProgressButtonWidget(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                      buttonTitle: Constants.cancelButton,
                                      tapCallback: (){
                                        // On hitting cancel button, change the state
                                        setState(() {
                                          // update the variable handling the current step value
                                          // going back one step i.e subtracting 1, until its 0
                                          if (currentStep > 0) {
                                            currentStep = currentStep - 1;
                                          } else {
                                            currentStep = 0;
                                          }
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: AppSize.smallMedium,),
                              ],
                            );
```

Answer (score 2):

After update of Flutter 2.8 , function changed for Custom Button in Flutter Stepper Widget .Please use this code.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iez17.png)

```
controlsBuilder: (context, details) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                      color: AppTheme.buttoncolor,
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
                        child: Text(
                          "Next",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                    if (_currentStep != 0)
                      CupertinoButton(
                          color: AppTheme.buttoncolor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                          child: Text(
                            "Back",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          onPressed: details.onStepCancel),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).